# How to prevent data tampering in a webpage sending data to a Google Sheet

Tags: http, security, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am implementing a solution where the data in a form is send to a Google Sheet (spreadsheet). So far so good, but I was thinking, what if a user manually plays with JS code in the browser to alter, for example, the row at where the new data should be inserted, eventually overwriting an already present row in the sheet?

Looking at Sheets API documentation at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js there is nothing about security.

So how this problem is generally solved? I doubt there's such a granular setting in Developer API limiting writing to only appending data?

Is my only chance in this case posting the request with data to be added to a Google App Script which will manage the logic and keep it isolated from tampering?

Comment: There is no solution beside a filtering server. Never trust user data.

Comment: @Cryptopat so basically the only solution is a backend (in this case Google Apps script)?

Comment: From my view yes. I have no knowledge of gdrive or gscript, but well about javascript, and javascript can't protect to what you describe, special crafted javascript. User -> backend sanitizing -> storage

Comment: From a earlier project, I have a remembrance of a way for making sure that forms aren't tempered implying tokens and encryption... but I don't remember exactly, and I am not sure if this still excludes the need of a backend...

Comment: Yep, there is html attributes that filter user inputs. There is also many ways to sanitize user inputs client side with js. But this won't protect your server, or your sheet, from a rewriting client side. It is very easy with debugers to see what is going on.